# Closing a Dropdown Menu using a list with a link inside the list child

Tags: jquery, html

I have here a dropdown list containing images of social media links/icons. Below these icons is a close button, also inside the list. What I want to happen is that when I click the button, the whole dropdown closes. But it seems that my code doesn't work.

```js
var indicator = 0;

$('.navigation-links-right > a.show').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if (indicator == 0) {
    $('a.show').css('background-color', '#2c2c2c');
    indicator = 1;
  } else if (indicator == 1) {
    $('a.show').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    indicator = 0;
  }
  
  $(this).parent().find('#sns-links').first().toggle();
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('#sns-links').hide();
});

$('.sns-links > li.btn-close').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('#sns-links').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation-links-right">
  <a class="nav-links"><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_01.png"></a>
  <a href="#" class="show nav-links" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_02.png"></a>
  <div id="sns-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_fb.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_blog.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_twitter.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_yt.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_ig.png"></a></li>
      <li class="btn-close"><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_close.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1st: I can't find the element with class `close` .. 2nd: use `$(this).closest("#sns-links").hide()` in close click event

Comment: Clicking the second button above the list does indeed hide the entire menu. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: i want that last list child when clicked, the whole dropdown closes. It's actually a close button.

Comment: edited my code already @Mohamed-Yousef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add `class="sns-links"` to `id="sns-links"` element
- `$('.sns-links > li.btn-close')` `>` selector means direct child so no need for `>` because the `li` not direct child
- To select the `sns-links` from close button use `.closest()`

```js
var indicator = 0;

$('.navigation-links-right > a.show').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if (indicator == 0) {
    $('a.show').css('background-color', '#2c2c2c');
    indicator = 1;
  } else if (indicator == 1) {
    $('a.show').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    indicator = 0;
  }
  
  $(this).parent().find('.sns-links').first().toggle();
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('.sns-links').hide();
});

$('.sns-links li.btn-close').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).closest('.sns-links').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation-links-right">
  <a class="nav-links"><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_01.png"></a>
  <a href="#" class="show nav-links" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_02.png"></a>
  <div class="sns-links" id="sns-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_fb.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_blog.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_twitter.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_yt.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_ig.png"></a></li>
      <li class="btn-close"><a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/icon/icon_sns_close.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: happy to hear that .. Have a great day :-) @AlexDeneris